# XML namespace is different with different implementations of DocumentBuilder/Transformer

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, classloader

I have 2 machines with identical java code on them. The code is about building an xml document using a document builder, and about converting that document to a string using a transformer. Both are instantiated using `factory.newInstance()`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

TransformerFactory tff = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer tf = tff.newTransformer();
```

However, I noticed they behaved differently. One 1 machine, inserting nodes in the document correctly turns empty namespaces into namespace with name equal to the empty string. On the other machine this doe not happen, and no namespace is inserted, and the element uses the parent's namespace instead.

So I compared the actual classes/classloaders for the factory's and the builder/transformer and they are indeed different. Here's the logfile for the correct output:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory class name:      com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
DocumentBuilderFactory class loader:        null
DocumentBuilderFactory class package:       package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.7

DocumentBuilder class name:             com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl
DocumentBuilder class loader:           null
DocumentBuilder class package:      package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.7

TransformerFactory class name:      com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
TransformerFactory class loader:        null
transformerFactory class package:       package com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.7

Transformer class name:             com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl
Transformer class loader:           null
Transformer class package:          package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.7
```

And here's the log for the WRONG output:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory class name:      org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
DocumentBuilderFactory class loader:        sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2ff40e1f
DocumentBuilderFactory class package:       package org.apache.xerces.jaxp

DocumentBuilder class name:             org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl
DocumentBuilder class loader:           sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2ff40e1f
DocumentBuilder class package:      package org.apache.xerces.jaxp

TransformerFactory class name:      org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
TransformerFactory class loader:        sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2ff40e1f
transformerFactory class package:       package org.apache.xalan.processor

Transformer class name:             org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl
Transformer class loader:           sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2ff40e1f
Transformer class package:          package org.apache.xerces.jaxp
```

I would like to tell the second machine to behave like the first one, but I'm not familiar with how cloassloaders work. Can anybody give me detailed info about:

1) Why is there a difference, what does classloading mean in this context?
2) How can I alter the default behaviour of machine #2 to use the same stuff as machine #1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably the wrong way to go. The versions of Xerces and Xalan from Apache are generally more reliable, robust, and standards conformant than the versions in the JDK. I would try to move everything to the Apache versions, and work out why your code is giving the wrong result in those cases, and fix it. We would need to see the details of exactly what code you think is giving the wrong result to tell you which product is actually behaving according to spec and which isn't. Choosing the product that is correct according to the spec is a much better approach than choosing the one that happens to do what you want.

You can control which versions JAXP loads in a number of ways: by changing what's on the classpath, by setting Java system properties, or by explicitly loading a chosen version. If you look at the Javadoc for classes like DocumentBuilderFactory and TransformerFactory it gives you a very detailed explanation.

Comment: I totally agree with your statement, except in this particular case I thought the official xml namespace spec says "no namespace" should be treated as "namespace == empty string", which the standard JDK version of transformer does, but the apache version does not. So I can only assumev the Apache transformer might be wrong on this one. That being said, I think its plausible for me to use apache AND "fix" their "bug" by altering my code to achieve the same result.

Comment: I'd like to know in more detail what operation you think is going wrong. You haven't even told us whether it's a DOM operation or an XSLT operation. The "official XML namespace spec" doesn't cover either DOM or XSLT, so I'm not sure of its relevance.

Comment: I have an element with namespace == null in my Document object. I convert this element to a string using the transform class. Good transform: convert the element to have a namespace equal to empty string. Bad transform: ignore namespace for that element.

Comment: If you mean you want to generate something like xmlns:p="", then that's legal only with XML Namespaces 1.1, which post-dates XSLT 1.0, so not many XSLT processors will support it. But the namespace rules are so complex and subtle, you need to provide much more detail. Try a new question.